# Confident interval different t.test and manual calculation

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

I am getting a different result when I apply t.test than when I do calculations manually, for a contrast of hypotheses, alternative hypothesis being mean1 < mean2. The observed value, degrees of freedom and p-value is the same, but not the interval and I can't figure what I'm doing wrong.

```
       a <- c(18,2,563,45,35,6,7,8)
       b <- c(7,5,4,6,8,5,4,2)
    
    
# function, left side, unequal variance
STAT_3 <- function ( x, y, NC ) {
          
          mean1 <- mean(x)
          mean2 <- mean(y)
          var1 <- var(x)
          var2 <- var(y)
          n1 <- length(x)
          n2 <- length(y)
          tobs <- (mean1 - mean2) / sqrt (var1/n1 + var2/n2)
          v <- (var1/n1 + var2/n2)^2 / ( ((var1/n1)^2 / (n1-1)) + ((var2/n2)^2 / (n2-1)) )
          tcrit <- qt( p = (1-NC/100)/2, df = v )
          pvalue <- pt( tobs, lower.tail=TRUE, df = v )
          return ( c(round(tobs,2), round(tcrit,2), pvalue, v) )
          
        }
        
    
        t.test(a,b,alternative='less',var.equal=FALSE)
        STAT_3(a,b,95)
```

Results I get are:

```
t.test:

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  a and b
t = 1.1745, df = 7.0013, p-value = 0.8607
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is less than 0
95 percent confidence interval:
     -Inf 210.0197
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
   85.500     5.125

manual:
 t = 1.1700000 tcrit = -2.3600000  p-value = 0.8607113  df = 7.0013281
```

Would anyone know why?

Comment: Where in the *STAT_3* function do you attempt to compute the confidence interval? See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/418504/237901) for how to do the calculation.

Comment: I calculate tcrit to estimate the rejection zone, so I get -inf,-2.36. Isn't that what t.test is giving as well?

Comment: Nope. t_crit is not the upper bound of the confidence interval. See the answer I linked above. PS: This is not the correct critical value for the "less" confidence interval anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have a balanced design with eight observations in each group. However, the two sample standard
deviations are massively different: $S_a=193.5, S_b
= 1.89.$

```
a <- c(18,2,563,45,35,6,7,8)     
b <- c(7,5,4,6,8,5,4,2)
summary(a); sd(a)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   2.00    6.75   13.00   85.50   37.50  563.00 
[1] 193.5436
summary(b); sd(b)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  2.000   4.000   5.000   5.125   6.250   8.000 
[1] 1.885092
```

Because of the equal sample sizes, the pooled and Welch t statistics will be equal, but of course
it's the Welch 2-sample t test you need to do.

```
t.test(a,b, alt="less")

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  a and b
t = 1.1745, df = 7.0013, p-value = 0.8607
alternative hypothesis: 
 true difference in means is less than 0
95 percent confidence interval:
     -Inf 210.0197
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
   85.500     5.125
```

I get the same result in R that you do.
The purpose of your uncommented and unmotivated
function `STAT-3`. I would try to de-bug that--if it is giving different results.